# Visa requirements for check out and in

Tags: visas, malaysia, sri-lankan-citizens, kul

I am a Sri Lankan passport holder. I have a New Zealand work visa. I am travelling from Auckland to Colombo via Kuala Lumpur, using Malaysian Airline. My flight has a layover in Kuala Lumpur of about 14 hours. I plan to check out and check in. Please let me know if I need a visa for check out and check in Malaysia and if a visa is required how do I get it?

Comment: By "check out and check in" do you mean that you will leave the airport (say, for sightseeing or staying at a hotel landside), or that you will pick up baggage and re-check it, or something different? "Check out" is not a term that's usually applied to air travel.

Answer (score 1):

You can transit KL without a visa if you fly on a single booking with Malaysia Airlines.

You will be required to remain in the international transit area in the main terminal, unless you also have a valid visa issued by Australia, China, Japan, Korea, New Zealand, Taiwan, or the USA. In this case, when your layover time is longer than 8 hours and you are flying on Malaysia Airlines, you may go through immigration in KL and transit landside, if your itinerary is from or to the country which issued that visa. (In your case that would be New Zealand.) You might do this, for instance, if you wish to stay at a hotel outside the airport before your next flight.

[See Timatic for additional details.](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=on&PASSTYPES=PASS&NA=LK&DE=LK&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&AR=00&TR=MY&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&user=FLIGHTWORX&subuser=FLIGHTWORX)